# Regex to match a text with special chars in it

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match a text with special chars `-,.+\/&` in it. The special chars must not be more than 2 subsequent and a special char can not be followed by space. More specifically I have to cover these cases:

```
some text/
/some text
some /text
```

I came up with this regex:

```
^[-\/,\.+\&]{0,1}[\p{L}]+[-\/,\.+\&]{0,1}([\s\-']?[-\/,\.+\&]{0,1}[\p{L}]+)([-\/,\.+\&]{0,1})$
```

It matches most of the cases that I need but fails to match for instance:
`some te&xt`. Every help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://regex101.com/) for debugging. When you stated that ` \ ` is not allowed, is ` \\\\\ ` allowed? You could just replace the undesired chars for empty.

Comment: The opposite. \\\\ is not allowed, \ is allowed.

Comment: Try [`"^(?!.*(?:[-,.+/&]\\s|[-,.+/&]{2}))\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*$"`](https://regex101.com/r/sV4eZ3/2).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiziev, digits are also not allowed. I forgot to mentioned it.

Comment: Try [`"^(?!.*(?:[-,.+/&]\\s|[-,.+/&]{2}))[^\\s\\d]+(?:\\s+[^\\s\\d]+)*$"`](https://regex101.com/r/sV4eZ3/3).

Comment: @analyser: Have you had time to check my second suggestion? Is the answer below working for you?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thanks a lot. The last regex do the job!

Comment: @analyser I posted with explanations. please consider accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"^(?!.*(?:[-,.+/&]\\s|[-,.+/&]{2}))[^\\s\\d]+(?:\\s+[^\\s\\d]+)*$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV4eZ3/3)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?:[-,.+/&]\\s|[-,.+/&]{2}))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a special char `[-,.+/&]` followed with a whitespace `\s`, or 2 consecutive special chars from `[-,.+/&]` set
- `[^\\s\\d]+` - 1 or more characters other than digit and whitespace
- `(?:\\s+[^\\s\\d]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[^\\s\\d]+` - 1 or more characters other than digit and whitespace
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
^[-\/,\.+\&\s]{0,1}([\p{L}][-\/,\.+\&\s]{0,1})+([-\/,\.+\&\s]{0,1}([\p{L}][-\/,\.+\&\s]{0,1})+)([\p{L}][-\/,\.+\&\s]{0,1})([-\/,\.+\&\s]{0,1})$
```